# Modify Shopify Shipping Rates at Checkout

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Is there a possibility that we could add a custom shipping price at checkout through an API call or script?
[image]

I want to modify the price based on some rules and I can't figure out how to do it in Shopify. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have Shopify Plus store then you can do this with script editor app. https://apps.shopify.com/script-editor

Comment: Shopify script editor only allows applying discounts to shipping prices. I want to modify the actual charge to a higher price instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by implementing your own CarrierService:

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/carrierservice

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app like this: https://apps.shopify.com/discount-on-cart-pro to display the shipping fee or shipping fee estimate in your cart summary. It’s also free shipping tier compatible, so you can promote that using the app as well.