# Can we increase shipping rates in shopify using shopify script?

Tags: shopify

I found similar question in the forum, and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276573/modify-shopify-shipping-rates-at-checkout) answer I come to know about Career service. Which looks promising initially, but after reading the doc from [here](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/carrierservice#top), I found that there is an issue for my use case.

This is my use case:

- There will be multiple items in the cart with different delivery dates set(I store delivery dates in the line_item property)
- now when user go to checkout the shipping rate has to be calculated based on the delivery dates(which are stored in the line item property for each line item)
- shipping price should be calculated like ...... if there is only one delivery day, we need to offer x price, if there are two different delivery dates we need to offer 2x price and so on....

so the issue is, Carrier Service uses Server side cashing and it will only ask for price if any of these(variant IDs, default shipping box weight and dimensions, variant quantities, carrier service ID, origin address, destination address, item weights and signatures) field change. It doesn't include line item properties(where I have stored delivery dates).

I have also checked the shopify scripts from [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/examples/shipping-scripts), but after some mockups I come to know that we can only provide discount to the existing shipping rates and can not add new shipping method, or increase shipping price for existing shipping method.

Please help me to find a solution for this problem.